# Change colors when using a continuous variable

Tags: r, r-highcharter

In the example below, `color` is mapped to **Petal.Width**. Custom colors are specified using `hc_colors()`. The new colors are not reflected in the plot.

```
library(highcharter)

cols <- c("red","green","blue")
hchart(iris,"scatter",hcaes(Petal.Width,Petal.Length,color=Petal.Width)) %>%
  hc_colors(colors=cols)
```

[image]

This approach also does not work with categorical colors. Here `color` is mapped to **Species**.

```
hchart(iris,"scatter",hcaes(Petal.Width,Petal.Length,color=Species)) %>%
  hc_colors(colors=cols)
```

[image]

But mapping `group` to **Species** seems to make it work somehow.

```
hchart(iris,"scatter",hcaes(Petal.Width,Petal.Length,group=Species)) %>%
  hc_colors(colors=cols)
```

[image]

How does one use custom colors when a continuous variable is mapped to color?

R 4.0.0
highcharter_0.8.2

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution.

```
library(highcharter)

cols <- c("red","green","blue")
hchart(iris,"scatter",hcaes(Petal.Width,Petal.Length,
       color=colorize(Petal.Width,cols)))
```

[image]

And a nifty little addition for a legend.

```
highcharter::hchart(iris,"scatter",hcaes(Petal.Width,Petal.Length,
                     color=colorize(Petal.Width,cols))) %>%
  hc_colorAxis(min=min(iris$Petal.Width),
               max=max(iris$Petal.Width),
               stops=color_stops(5,cols))
```

[image]